# Test opcode ASM complication

Tags: assembly

i came to a line like this in ollydbg

edi is ffffffff

```
test edi,edi
jl short
```

the debugger states the jump is taken, from what i understand TEST performs a mathematical AND operation, but ffffffff AND with ffffffff still is ffffffff. all i want to know is, how is the result interpreted, JL is a signed jump, when it states jump if less, is it reffering to less then zero? since ffffffff = -1 signed, i hope you get what i'm saying, edi register tested against itself gives same exact result, so how is it less...

Comment: `test edi, edi \ jl` somewhere tests the sign of `edi`. `jl` jumps if `SF xor OF`. `test` sets `SF` to the sign of the result, and sets `OF` to zero. So it'll jump if `edi` is negative. btw: I just told you that recently.

Answer (score 0):

This code is testing if the sign bit (the most significant bit) is set and jumps if it is.

Comment: your saying that the result is either negative or positive that affects the jump? if edi was 0 then jz would follow, if edi was 1 then jg would follow? so it falls like this -32768  0  32767 ?  anything between -32768  -1 will be negative or jump less and anything with 1 - 32767 will be jump greater?

Comment: `jl` means jump if the sign flag is set, otherwise continue with the next instruction. `test edi, edi` sets the sign flag if the value of `edi` has the sign bit set, otherwise it clears it.